# Javascript - Template Engine

Tags: javascript, template-engine

Nowadays, we can find many JS templating engines like KnockOut, Mustache, Underscore, ... Can you please tell me what are the advantages of an architecture based upon theses engines ? and/or when to use them ? Is it better (maintainability, dev costs, reliability, ...) than generating all HTML from server-side ?

Is it a good architecture to expose feeds (rest service in json) and do some stuff on client side (micro templating) ?

Answer (score 31):

Linkedin has done great research, [have a look at this page](http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more).

Comment: this is really a great link !

Answer (score 7):

The main advantage of templates is optimization of the amount of data passed to the client it make response faster, reduces your traffic costs, and increase throughput of your servers.

Comment: +1 It should also be noted that it stresses the client more and makes the client (slightly) thicker.